# Different ThreadPools for Seam's @Asynchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, java-ee-5, seam2

We have an application based on Java EE 5 and the JBoss Seam 2 framework. There we use the `@Asynchronous` annotation a lot for background jobs.

Now, we have the problem, that those jobs may be of different priority and using a global limitation of the ThreadPool may prevent important jobs from running.

So, the question is, how to use different ThreadPools (say a low and a high prio), which have different limitations and assign the jobs to one of it?